Inner product and norms equality
I was trying to understand the solution to exercize 32 sec 6.5 of Friedberg et al. Linear Algebra. The exercize define an Householding function $H_u(x) = x - 2\langle x, u \rangle u$,  and then ask to find a $u$ such that $H_u(x) = \theta y $ for some $\theta$ such that $|\theta| = 1$, and for some $y$ such that $\lvert\lvert{x}\vert\vert = \vert\vert y\vert\vert$. Then it gives an hint, to choose $\theta$ to be real and $u = \frac{x - \theta y}{\vert\vert x - \theta y \vert\vert}$.
The choice of $\theta$ is $\langle x, y\rangle$, and then substituting the equation of the function lead to $$H_u(x) = x - 2 \frac{\langle x, x-\theta y \rangle (x-\theta y)}{\vert\vert x-\theta y\vert\vert^2}$$. Then i was stuck at this passagge $$H_u(x) = x - \frac{2\vert\vert x \vert\vert ^2 - 2\langle x, \theta y \rangle}{\vert\vert x-\theta y\vert\vert^2}(x - \theta y)$$. Then i found a solution that transform like this and this is the point i can't understand $$H_u(x) =x - \frac{ \vert\vert x \vert\vert^2 - 2\langle x,y \rangle + \vert\vert \theta y \vert\vert^2}{\vert\vert x-\theta y\vert\vert^2}(x- \theta y)$$
Then the solution is straightforward but the passage between the second and the third equation is missing to me.

By assumption, $\|x\| = \| y \|$ and $|\theta| = 1$, so
$$
 2 \| x \|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \|x\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \|\theta y\|^2.
$$
Edit You seem to be missing the $\theta$ in front of the $y$ in the inner product in the third equation.
